# Why would one use runBlocking(IO) instead of just runBlocking in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Spring Boot app and when handling a given request I need to call upstream services in a parallel and wait for the result to complete before returning them in my own response.

In the existing code base, I noticed that in order to do so, the pattern is to use `runBlocking(IO) { ... }`

```kotlin
@Service
class MyUpstreamService {
    fun getSomething() = 1
}

@RestController
class MyController(
    val upstream: MyUpstreamService
) {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    fun foo() =
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val a = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            val b = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            a.await() + b.await()
        }
}
```

This works as expected.

Now for some reasons I need to set the scope of `MyUpstreamService` to `@RequestScope` and if I do so, I get the following exception as soon as I access `MyUpstreamService` from within the `runBlocking(IO) { ... }`  block:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
```

If I do not use the `Dispatchers.IO` context, then everything works fine.

So the question is why would one use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) { .. }`  instead of just `runBlocking { .. }`  when waiting for several async calls to complete?

For completeness, here is the entire snippet demonstrating the question.

- `GET /bar` works
- `GET /foo` throws the exception

```kotlin
@RequestScope
@Service
class MyUpstreamService(
    // val currentUser: CurrentUser
) {
    fun getSomething() = 1
}

@RestController
class MyController(
    val upstream: MyUpstreamService
) {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    fun foo() =
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val a = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            val b = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            a.await() + b.await()
        }

    @GetMapping("/bar")
    fun bar() =
        runBlocking {
            val a = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            val b = async { upstream.getSomething() }
            a.await() + b.await()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runBlocking` without particular dispatcher means that all coroutines inside are launched in a special single-threaded event loop dispatcher backed by the thread that you're blocking. This, in turn, means your coroutines would not run in parallel.

`runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)` means the nested coroutines run on the IO dispatcher, which is backed by a pool of threads of dynamic size, and thus the coroutines are effectively run in parallel (within some limit). At the same time, it's still a `runBlocking`, which means the calling thread would still be blocked while waiting for the nested coroutines to complete, but it would not be used to do any work.

> for some reasons I need to set the scope of MyUpstreamService to @RequestScope

When you do this, Spring creates one service instance by request - and this is done based on the request's *thread* (by using some `ThreadLocal` machinery I assume). As we have just seen, `runBlocking` without dispatcher actually uses the calling thread, so the request thread, and that is why this mechanism still works. If you use `runBlocking(IO)` and dispatch on other threads, you're breaking this Spring mechanism.

Now I haven't done Spring dev in a while, so I'm not 100% sure how to fix your problem. But I believe a good start would be to stop using the thread-per-request model if you're using coroutines, and thus switch to [`suspend` functions in your controllers using Spring WebFlux](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines). I think it will still not allow to use `@RequestScope`, though, because you would be giving up the "request thread" concept altogether. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28235

Comment: A solution could be to make a `ThreadContextElement` that updates Spring's `RequestContextHolder`